# Как проверить , существует ли элемент в цикле

Tags: django

Цикл фор перебирает список пользователь , оператор **if** проверяет в друзьях ли он как я могу определить что из всего цикла оператор if так ничего и не нашёл. Или для этого обязательно создавать свои операторы или фильтры для шаблонов django

```
{% for fr in users.friend.all %}
    {% if fr.user2 == id_user %}
        <button>удалить из друзей</button>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```